# Отражение и встроенные структуры

Tags: golang

Не могу получить доступ к полям встроенной структуры. Вот пример:

```
type X1 struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 string
}

type X2 struct {
    X1
    Field3 string
    Field4 string
}

func TestTemp(t *testing.T) {
    struct1 := reflect.TypeOf(X2{})
    for cikl := 0; cikl < struct1.NumField(); cikl++ { // <- здесь struct1.NumField() показывает 3
        fmt.Println("structType1 [", cikl, "]:", struct1.Field(cikl).Name)
    }
}
```

В результате будет:

```
structType1 [ 0 ]: X1
structType1 [ 1 ]: Field3
structType1 [ 2 ]: Field4
```

Соответственно, мы не видим сами поля, мы видим только встраиваемую структуру `structType1 [ 0 ]: X1`.
Даже если мы пройдёмся отдельно по встроенной структуре X1 и узнаем название полей, как обратиться к данным этих полей относительно X**2**?
Т.е. через рефлексия посмотреть или изменить X**2**.Field**1**?

Comment: Что значит "относительно X2"? `X2.X1.Field1` - это то же самое, что `X2.Field1`.

Comment: Да, не врубился. Сбил постулат про перекрытие методов, когда можно напрямую обратиться к оригинальному методу через обращение к встроенной структуре. Думал с полями так же...

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение (кратко):

```
x := X2{}
x.Field1 = "test"
structValue := reflect.ValueOf(&x).Elem().FieldByName("Field1")
structValue.SetString("pass")
fmt.Println(x.Field1)  // pass
```